# What are vscode settings for linux kernel driver development?

Tags: c, linux, driver, visual-studio-code

I need to build simple kernel driver in visual studio code
with bellow task configurations:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "make",
    "isShellCommand": true
}
```

but in my Makefile

```
obj-m := hellochardev.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

it assign `M`  my home directory, is there a solution to correct this problem?

here is build log:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/build/ M=/home/mohsen modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/mohsen/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/mohsen/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mohsen] Error 2
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/home/mohsen' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' faile
```

Comment: `/home/mohsen/Makefile: No such file or directory`. Where is the `Makefile`? `M` should contain the directory of the source module.

Comment: I want to don't touch my Makefile and just change build directory in vscode

Comment: Well you succeeded. It can't touch your `Makefile` if it can't see it. And it won't build anything without any `Makefile`. So what's the question?